# What is "DataBindingComponent" class in android databinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have seen the DataBindingComponent in the official API doc.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html

> This interface is generated during compilation to contain getters for
>   all used instance BindingAdapters. When a BindingAdapter is an
>   instance method, an instance of the class implementing the method must
>   be instantiated. This interface will be generated with a getter for
>   each class with the name get* where * is simple class name of the
>   declaring BindingAdapter class/interface. Name collisions will be
>   resolved by adding a numeric suffix to the getter.
>
> An instance of this class may also be passed into static or instance
>   BindingAdapters as the first parameter.
>
> If using Dagger 2, the developer should extend this interface and
>   annotate the extended interface as a Component.

However, I cannot find any example usage of this class in the web. Can anyone know what it is and how to use it.

I tried to make some simple code and debug it to see what's is it but it showed null variable on the `a` variable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
    android.databinding.DataBindingComponent a = DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent();
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
}
```

Comment: you can follow this official guide https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html or  this tutorial http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/08/android-data-binding-tutorial-2.html

Comment: I do know how to use android databinding. But I saw this class "DataBindingComponent " is used in few method in "DataBindingUtil" class. I would like to know what is this and how can it be used.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.html) we know

> This interface is generated during compilation to contain getters for all used instance BindingAdapters. When a BindingAdapter is an instance method, an instance of the class implementing the method must be instantiated. This interface will be generated with a getter for each class with the name get* where * is simple class name of the declaring BindingAdapter class/interface. Name collisions will be resolved by adding a numeric suffix to the getter.
>
> An instance of this class may also be passed into static or instance BindingAdapters as the first parameter.
>
> If using Dagger 2, the developer should extend this interface and annotate the extended interface as a Component.

This tells us this interface is used and generated for injecting a factory for instances implementing custom `@BindingAdapter` methods. Like this you can configure the data bindings for different situations or layouts or supply it with a more general state. If you have a look at the default `DataBindingComponent` class in Android Studio you find it located in ***build/generated/source/apt/dev***.

The methods you can use with the `DataBindingComponent` are

- [DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#setDefaultComponent(android.databinding.DataBindingComponent))
- [DataBindingUtil.inflate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean,%20android.databinding.DataBindingComponent))
- [DataBindingUtil.bind()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#bind(android.view.View,%20android.databinding.DataBindingComponent))

Considering you define an interface like

```
public interface Foo {
    @BindingAdapter("foobar")
    void fooBar(View view, String baz);
}
```

an `android.databinding.DataBindingComponent` interface gets generated

```
public interface DataBindingComponent {
    di.pkg.Foo getFoo();
}
```

This `@BindingAdapter` host now gets used in your data bindings, but you need to implement the interface yourself and use it with one of the methods given above like

```
DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(new DataBindingComponent(){
    @Override
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return new Foo() {
            @Override
            public void fooBar(View view, String baz) {
                if (view instanceof TextView) ((TextView) view).setText(baz);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

In your example you get null from `DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent()` because you've never set the default component yourself.

Comment: Your third code spinet showed a compile-time error since "Foo" class is not the type of "android.databinding.DataBindingComponent". If I understand it correctly, this DataBindingComponent could be used as developing a third-party data binding library since the interface can be implemented and also the Component could be set manually (which means can be developed in OOP ).

Comment: You're right. I forgot to implement the component itself. I'm not 100% sure how `@BindingAdapter` works with libraries. The `DataBindingComponent` can be used with dependency injection instead of the static approach. Making it easier to change the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would try to create a sample to make the binding be more flexible since the guide leaded he developer to write some static methods for binding instead of making it as an object or being extendable.

Answer (score 25):

After reading the answer from @tynn , the DataBindingComponent class can also be as "object" scope of data binding method. Instead of setting all the method in static way, the following example can be used to be extendable and custom. For example, we setup 3 binding methods for ImageView, TextView and View type. You can setup the interface first ( like Retrofit 2 setup interface for API)

**1. Setup 3 interface first**

**ImageViewBindingInterface.java**

```
public interface ImageViewBindingInterface {
    @BindingAdapter({"bind:imageUrl", "bind:error"})
    public  void loadImage(ImageView view, String url, Drawable error);
}
```

**TextViewBindingInterface.java**

```
public interface TextViewBindingInterface {
    @BindingAdapter({"bind:font"})
      void setFont(TextView textView, String fontName);
}
```

**ViewBindingInterface.java**

```
public interface ViewBindingInterface {
    @BindingAdapter("android:paddingLeft")
    public  void setPaddingLeft(View view, int padding);
    @BindingAdapter("android:onViewAttachedToWindow")
    public  void setListener(View view, ViewBindingAdapter.OnViewAttachedToWindow attached);
}
```

**2. The DataBindingComponent.java should be updated automatically as @tynn mentioned like the following.**

> If you have a look at the default DataBindingComponent class in
>   Android Studio you find it located in build/generated/source/apt/dev.

```
public interface DataBindingComponent {
    example.com.testerapplication.binding.ViewBindingInterface getViewBindingInterface();
    example.com.testerapplication.binding.TextViewBindingInterface getTextViewBindingInterface();
    example.com.testerapplication.binding.ImageViewBindingInterface getImageViewBindingInterface();
}
```

**3. Build your own implementation method for binding.**

**BaseImageViewBinding.java**

```
public class BaseImageViewBinding implements ImageViewBindingInterface{
    @Override
    public void loadImage(ImageView view, String url, Drawable error) {
          Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(url).error(error).into(view);
    }
}
```

**BaseTextViewBinding.java**

```
public class BaseTextViewBinding implements TextViewBindingInterface {
    @Override
    public void setFont(TextView textView, String fontName) {
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName));
    }
}
```

**BaseViewBinding.java**

```
public class BaseViewBinding implements ViewBindingInterface {
    @Override
    public void setPaddingLeft(View view, int padding) {
        view.setPadding(padding,
                view.getPaddingTop(),
                view.getPaddingRight(),
                view.getPaddingBottom());
    }
    @Override
    public void setListener(View view, ViewBindingAdapter.OnViewAttachedToWindow attached) {

    }
}
```

**4. Set your OwnDatabindingComponent**

```
public class MyOwnDefaultDataBindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public ViewBindingInterface getViewBindingInterface() {
        return new BaseViewBinding();
    }
    @Override
    public TextViewBindingInterface getTextViewBindingInterface() {
        return new BaseTextViewBinding();
    }
    @Override
    public ImageViewBindingInterface getImageViewBindingInterface() {
        return new BaseImageViewBinding();
    }
}
```

**5. Setup your default DataBindingComponent in the Application**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(new MyOwnDefaultDataBindingComponent());
    }
}
```

Using this method should be fine to make the custom data binding in a custom way and can be extensible.